# JSON string to Java object with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization

This is probably one of those questions where the title says it all.

I am quite fascinated by the ObjectMapper's `readValue(file, class)` method, found within the Jackson library which reads a JSON string from a file and assigns it to an object.

I'm curious if this is possible to do by simply getting JSON from a string and applying it to an object.

Some sort of alternative `readValue()` method, which takes a **String**, instead of a file, and assigns it to an object?

For instance, while the default `readValue(file, class)` method looks like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Student student = mapper.readValue("C:\\student.json", Student.class);
```

I was wondering if there was some method in Jackson, which allowed the following:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Student student = mapper.readValue("{\"id\":100,\"firstName\":\"Adam\"}", Student.class);
```

The second example takes a string and an object of a class while the first one takes a file and an object of a class.

I just want to cut out the middle man, in this case, the file.

Is this doable or does no such method exist within the constraints of Jackson?

Comment: Please read the [javadoc](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue(java.lang.String,java.lang.Class))...

Comment: Show your Student Class.

Comment: [`ObjectMapper#readValue(String, Class)` exists.](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) Did you miss it?

Comment: @MattBall Oh my God, it does. I'm such an idiot. Thank you never the less, friend.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this,

You can't create a new string like your doing.

```
    String string = "{\"id\":100,\"firstName\":\"Adam\"}";
    Student student = mapper.readValue(string, Student.class);
```

Comment: Constructing an ObjectMapper is relatively expensive; I can't recommend doing it every time a method is called.

Comment: Yea, I got ride of that when I saw the reason why it was failing is OP didn't but his string in ""

Comment: I'm a complete idiot, and I feel embarrassed to have asked this question. Thank you both for helping clear up my retardation.

Comment: Thank you @djc391, I will. Thank you both for not making me feel too horrid about such a dumb question.

Comment: I have a json which has inner Arrays and inner Arrays. Consider each array has an object. In this case how to map json with inner Arrays to POJO java objects.

Answer (score 4):

And instead of handling errors in every `mapper.readValue(json,Class)` you can write a helper class which has another `Generic` method.

and use

```
String jsonString = "{\"id\":100,\"firstName\":\"Adam\"}";
Student student = JSONUtils.convertToObject(jsonString,Student.class);
```

I'm returning `null`and fancying printing trace & checking null later on. You can handle error cases on your own way.

```
public class JSONUtils {
    public static String convertToJSON(Object object)
    {
        ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        String json;
        try {
            json = ow.writeValueAsString(object);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return convertToJSON(e);
        }
        return json;
    }


    public static <T> T convertToObject(Class<T> clazz,String jsonString)
    {
        try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return (T)mapper.readValue(jsonString, clazz);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```